# Disable Yes button in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, alert

I would like to disable Yes button in an Alert box. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You mean disable or hide?

I don't think you can enable/disable buttons in a Alert box, but you choose which buttons will be shown, for example:

```
Alert.show('Text Copied!', 'Alert Box', Alert.YES | Alert.NO);
```

Valid buttons:

```
mx.controls.Alert.OK
mx.controls.Alert.YES
mx.controls.Alert.NO
mx.controls.Alert.CANCEL
```

Full documentation here: [Alert control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_19.html)

If you really meant to enable/disable buttons, you could make your own MXML component based on `TitleWindow`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Leo. I am just trying to disable not hide.

I think I have design a new Component with TitleWindow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;

private var theAlert:Alert;

public function showAlert():void
{
  theAlert = Alert.show("Saving Changes...", "", Alert.YES + Alert.NO);
  theAlert.mx_internal::alertForm.mx_internal::buttons[0].enabled = false;
}

public function hideAlert():void
{
  PopUpManager.removePopUp(theAlert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the examples on this [flex examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/17/disabling-an-alert-control-in-flex/#more-834) page help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend the Alert class with your own custom class. Add a bitmask that controls which buttons are enabled or disabled. Then override createChildren() and disable the buttons as they are created.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest to you to create you own custom alert, see an example [here](http://webinky.com/flex/custom-alert-in-flex)